# Extract any and all characters between " " using Big Query REGEX

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I need to extract just '"Loc":"CART",' from this larger string:

```
hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = {"AV":6,"CV":1,"PV":1,"AS":"1,2,3,4","Loc":"CART","PN":"Supreme Lover's® - 12\" Medium","PS":"6716a12c-0067-4d72-b560-a0dbd1197185"}
```

"Loc" will always stay the same, the value where "CART" exists could change.

I am trying the following sql:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, '"Loc":".*",') as Recommendation_Location
```

but it is returning the entire rest of the string starting after "Loc".

I am using standard sql in Google BigQuery, and have been looking at all the documentation but can't seem to figure out how to grab just the characters inside of the quotes.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Instead of

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, '"Loc":".*",')
```

which returns

```
Row Recommendation_Location  
1   "Loc":"CART","PN":"Supreme Lover's® - 12" Medium",
```

use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, '"Loc":".*?",')
```

which returns

```
Row Recommendation_Location  
1   "Loc":"CART",
```

As you can see the only difference is - you need to add extra `?` char into regexp